# Why $sgn(\sigma)=(-1)^{j-1} sgn(\tau)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

**Problem:**

Suppose that $\sigma \in \mathcal{S}_k=\{f:\{1,...,k\} \to \{1,...,k\} \mbox{ is bijective} \}$. We know that $\sigma$ has $sgn(\sigma) \in \{-1,1\}$. Suppose that $\sigma(1)=j$.

Let us define $\tau \in \mathcal{S}_{k-1}$ in this way:

$$\tau(i)= 
\begin{cases}
\sigma(i+1) \mbox{ if } \sigma(i+1)<j \\ \sigma(i+1)-1 \mbox{ if } \sigma(i+1)>j
\end{cases}  \mbox{      for all }i \in \{1,...,k-1\}$$

Why can we conclude $sgn(\sigma)=(-1)^{j-1}sgn(\tau)$?

Comment: Hint: how can you change $\sigma$ to $\tau$ by exchanging values in pairs?

Comment: @J.G. Could you please explain me more? I cannot understand what are you referring to

Answer (score 0):

Let $\xi$ be permutation on $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ that leaves $\{1,2,\ldots,j-1\}$ unchanged and moves $\{j,j+1,\ldots,k\}$ to $\{k,j,j+1,\ldots,k-1\}$. Then $\xi \circ \sigma$ is basically $\tau$ with $k$ inserted to the beginning – so composing it with $k$-cycle we will get $\tau$ with additional $k$ at the end, which has the same sign as $\tau$. Then, since sign of $t$-cycle is $(-1)^{t-1}$,

$$(-1)^{k-1} \cdot (-1)^{k-j} \cdot sgn(\sigma) = sgn(\tau),$$

which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Could you please add more details? What do you mean with "$\xi \circ \sigma$ is basically $\tau$"?